# Set icon for custom right-click context menu item in Windows 11

Tags: icons, registry, contextmenu, windows-11

Thought I'd try asking this for Windows 11 since it doesn't seem to be answered for that version.  (Asked and answered for many older operating systems but I can't get those examples to work in my test in Windows 11.)  [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681032/set-icon-for-custom-right-click-context-menu-item-for-all-desktop-shortcuts-win) even has a comment that it worked for someone in Windows 10.

In Windows 11, I have the following registry entries, and the context menu "Show more options" does display (end execute) my custom menu addition, just without the standard Excel Icon that I want displayed):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\JWC_Templates]
@="JWC_Templates (Excel)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\JWC_Templates\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE\" /n \"C:\\Users\\jcorr\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Custom Office Templates\\JWC Templates-XLTM Source (v2.02.00).xltm\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\JWC_Templates\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE\" "
"Org_Default"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\VFS\\Windows\\Installer\\{90160000-000F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\\xlicons.exe,31"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\JWC_Templates\Icon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE\" "

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\JWC_Templates\Position]
@="Top"
```

I've tried using various values in the following Keys and with no luck:  `[DefaultIcon]` `[Icon]` and `[Position]`

Any idea how to add icon to context menu item in Windows 11